# Graphics fuzzy in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, graphics

Having just installed 12.10 I notice that I get fuzzy text and icons that change when I move my mouse over them. See picture below as an example. What could be wrong? I have a NVIDIA Quadro 600 graphics card.

[image]

Comment: Using which drivers?

Comment: I actually don't know. I assumed the Ubuntu loads the necessary drivers as part of the packages. Good idea let me check. maybe NVIDIA Quadro needs special drivers

Comment: Update your system fully, and check again.

Comment: Added NVIDIA specific drivers and problem resolved. This question was me being silly. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your drivers. If the problem persists, then you could try to test the card in another system or OS to see if it works normally. If it doesn't work in another system or under windows then it might be a hardware issue.